# What street foods can I eat in Italy?

Tags: food-and-drink, italy, local-cuisine, local-knowledge

Sometimes I don't want to go eat at restaurants. So, What are the typical foods that are available on streets in Italy?

Comment: I don't think Italy is big on street foods. On the other hand there are certainly pizzarias where you can sit at a bench and get your food served quickly. Oh wait..I forgot gelato.

Comment: In season, you can buy stuffed olives from a market stand in Urbino.  They are gourmet class and there's nothing in the world quite like it.  But on balance, nearly every town/village in Italy has an open air market where you can purchase fruit and veg.  So I'm close voting as too broad.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14211/how-can-i-find-out-what-the-typical-fast-food-is-for-a-particular-country you may wanto to look at this

Comment: In three weeks in Italy, I don't recall seeing anything I would call "street food."  But neither I nor my sister nor my brother-in-law got ill from any of the numerous things we bought by just walking into a shop and buying something sitting on display.  Also, the pizza was better than any I ever had elsewhere, and did not taste like bread.  I've never had pizza anywhere that tasted like hot dogs!

Comment: ice-cream is not really "street food" in Italy.

Comment: @Fattie: Why do you think so? As far as I've seen, ice cream is almost exclusively sold in cones in Italy, for taking away.

Comment: Hi guys, my interpretation of the loaded term "street food" just does not match.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

## Main Courses

#### Pizza al Trancio

The single best street food that you can have in Italy is [*pizza al trancio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_al_taglio) i.e. a slice of pizza on the go. It doesn't get more typical and local than this. You find this in both bakeries and dedicated *pizzeria al trancio*. Some cities cut slices out of round pizzas, others out of rectangular ones. In both cases, you walk in the shop, pay a couple Euros, and leave with a steaming slice of pizza.

[image: pizza al trancio]

#### Piadina

Second in our list is [*piadina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piadina) which is a warm flatbread sandwhich-type concoction originating from the Romagna region. Fillings vary, although you'll typically get ham and cheese versions. Why get a basic sandwhich when you can get a true Italian piadina?

[image: Piadina]

#### Focaccia

Third is [*focaccia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focaccia), which is a simple bread-like product made with pizza dough and some other magic, depending on region and city. You can have them plain, with herbs, olives, tomatoes, or even filled with ham, cheese or whatever you find. Like in the case of pizza, both bakeries and dedicated shops sell them.

[image: Focaccia]

#### Pizzette

Where you find focaccia, you're likely to find *pizzette* (literally: small pizzas) too. Get a bunch of these and fight your hunger.

[image: Pizzette]

#### Arancini, Supplì, Crocchette, Olive all'Ascolana

In pizzerie, and some bakeries, you'll find a variety of fried products such as [*arancini*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arancini), [*supplì*](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGyKbuqt7JAhXFfRoKHR8TBsAQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSuppl%25C3%25AC&usg=AFQjCNF8TcGRToMH8ei1Os4b3DuSd3jLdw&bvm=bv.110151844,d.d2s), [*crocchette*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocch%C3%A8), and *olive all'ascolana* (stuffed olives) (all pictured below in the order they appear). These first are a rice-based dish originating from Sicily, whereas the last are typical to Rome and other southern cities. Crocchette are mash-potato-based and are found mostly anywhere.

[image: Arancini]
[image: Supplì]
[image: Crocchette]
[image: olive ascolana]

#### Pizza Bianca

Typical in Rome is *pizza bianca*, which is something between bread, pizza and focaccia (see the image below). Most bakeries will have some. The best thing you can do is to walk into a place that sells both bread and sliced-meats and ask them to fill it up for you. Such a place is called a *negozio di alimentari* or *drogheria* in Italy. There you go, this is my secret to eating cheap when touring Rome: get pizza bianca and fill it up.

[image: Pizza bianca]

#### Porchetta

Also typical from Rome, although originating from Ariccia, is [*porchetta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porchetta), a spit-roasted pig. Eat a porchetta sandwich and you'll never forget it.

[image: porchetta]

#### Fried Fish

Fried-fish shops (*friggitorie*) are a somewhat recent trend, but their availability is increasing around the country. You'll typically get a takeaway cone of oil-proof paper filled with fried fish for a couple euros. Beware that those calamari are scolding hot!

[image: Pesce fritto al cono]

#### Panzerotti

*Panzerotti* are another bakery product, which look very much like a small *calzone*, only fried. Although originating from Puglia, these can be found in many other regions in Italy. Indeed, Luini in Milan became famous with these.

[image: Panzerotto]

---

## Desserts

#### Gelato

Pizza and gelato? It's as if I were compiling the most possibly stereotypical representation of Italy. Turns out though that these stereotypes are awesome! As you roam around Italian cities, you'll find them scattered with *gelaterie* i.e. ice-cream shops. No, none of that pre-made industrially-processed Algida garbage. In Italy you'll find real hand-made ice cream in a million different flavours, shapes and decorations. Don't forget to ask for whipped cream on top.

[image: Gelato]

#### Patisseries

Every city has their own patisseries, most of which you can eat while walking. Look for a *pasticceria* i.e. a patisserie shop and ask for the typical desert. In Napoli that would be a *sfogliatella*, in Sicily maybe a small *cassata* or a *cannolo*, in Rome why not try Pompi's famous *tiramisù* (patisserie images are shown below in the order they appear)?

[image: sfogliatella]
[image: cassata]
[image: pompi tiramisù]

Other patisseries like *cornetti* (italian version of croissants) and *bombe fritte* can be found all around the country (patisserie images are shown below in the order they appear).

[image: cornetti]
[image: bombe fritte]

Comment: Arancini can be amazing. 
No mention of Gelato though?

Comment: Also, simple panini (which is italian for sandwich, and does not necessarly mean hot) with local cheeses, hams, sausages, vegetables...

Comment: Please do not use code formatting (backticks) for emphasis. If you feel it is necessary (personally, I think this answer would be fine without), using bold, with asterisks, is far more appropriate. In addition to being a quite-jarring break with the typical style of the text, the underlying web markup indicates that text is “code,” which can be and is handled in special ways by, for example, screen readers for the blind. Some of these even read the code out letter-by-letter! So please only use code formatting (backticks, four-space indentation of a paragraph) for actual computer code.

Comment: I have just eaten. I read this and now I am hungry again.

Comment: **This is amazing!!** actually I never knew there are these kinds of foods. So it's gonna be a food travel not _travel_. Pizza al Trancio will be the first on my list Thanks @JoErNanO

Comment: Dammit I have to go to Italia again now :) 
+1 for Gelato. You can get several flavors for less than 5 euros, walk to a different shop, and they'd have a different set of flavors.

Comment: I just bought a ticket to Rome...

Comment: @KRyan I use backticks for words that aren't written in English, and sometimes for currency codes since I don't have all the symbols on my keyboard. I don't use them for emphasis. I did not know about screen readers. You make a good point. I'll go edit backticks out of my posts as I find them. Feel free to do so as well. ;)

Comment: Great answer, but you are missing **döner kebab**. While not traditionally Italian, it's as ubiquitous as pizza and gelato nowadays.

Comment: Another thing I'd suggest to mention is that you can have **gelato-stuffed brioches** in most ice cream shops. While technically a dessert, there's usually enough of it to make a full meal even for the hungry.

Comment: I put on a kilo just reading that

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Ciao. I didn't put kebab in the list because it just doesn't belong there. It's a matter of gastronomical pride. :D

Comment: @FedericoPoloni the question does specifically ask for _typical_ food, so JoErNanO made the right choice there

Comment: @JoErNanO I typically see italics used for non-English words, so that may be best.

Comment: @KRyan Done. Italics seem to work just fine. ;)

Comment: thanks for taking the time for the fantastic answer, but what's that horrible US-chain-style pizza in the first photo?!!

Comment: I went to Rome in September and the Gelato ruled my world. Portions are vast so hold onto your hats!

Comment: I went to Rome in October and there were lots of stalls roasting and selling chestnuts. Real street food! (However, I don't like chestnuts, and although they were freshly cooked there are always concerns about such food...)

Comment: That "horrible US-chain-style pizza" picture was actually taken in [Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pizza_al_taglio.jpg).

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer lists the popular foods available in almost all Italy but I think you can usually find some local (and sometimes strange) street food.

In Florence, for example, it's very popular [lampredotto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampredotto), in Tuscany it's not rare to find roventini (a sort of fried blood served with parmesan or chocolate).

Abruzzo has [arrosticini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrosticini)  .

In Sicilia is famous meuza (spleen).

These are some examples, if you visit Italy I suggest you to always give a try to local street food.

Answer (score 2):

All the foodies listed in the other answers definitely deserve a mention, and here we already put together more than a thresold overview.

I'd like to add that **pizza** as a street food comes in two formats mainly:

- slices

[image: slice of pizza]

- squares

[image: squares of pizza]

We call these *pizza al taglio* or *tranci di pizza* but I couldn't actually say if any of the two names refers precisely to one of the two shapes or both in general. Slices are generally thiner, while squares are often more visibly risen.

---

Sweet or savoury **croissants and pastries** (*cornetti* or *brioche*) are also common, plain or stuffed.

[image: cornetti]

---

Pizza is sold nationwide while other foodies named in this page are regional and more or less likely to be found elsewhere. In the area of Romagna (also, Emilia and north of Marche), where **piadina** rules, you can find a genuine variant called *crescione* (or *cassone* in Rimini):

[image: crescioni]

These are filled, closed and only then baked, rather than baked both sides, cut in two and filled at the end. If you order *piade e crescioni*, remember that piade are faster while crescioni need 15 minutes or so on the heat! But they are my favourite...

---

Finally, Naples is famous for pizza, but in there they also make *frittatina*, fried egg stuffed with pasta or other.

[image: frittatina]

Original urls of the images: [pizza slice](https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0d/b4/79/d7/trancio-di-pizza-margherita.jpg), [pizza square](https://i.pinimg.com/474x/41/bd/cd/41bdcd080f4078eeac979279e7521ac8.jpg), [cornetti](https://www.negroni.com/sites/default/files/croissant-salati-per-la-colazione.jpg), [crescioni/cassoni](https://www.vitadasani.it/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/Cassoni-oo2aqzyryekrccfdo47yhh7xvtr2pkjzxczmdywb5s.jpg), [frittatina napoletana](https://static.cookist.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2018/01/frittata-di-maccheroni.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

In winter, you might see a stand selling roasted chestnuts. They taste great!