# First time in Barcelona: affordable places to eat for a student

Tags: budget, food-and-drink, spain, barcelona

I will be arriving in Barcelona on the 13th of September and I will be staying together with my girlfriend for 6 nights.

Although I have a job, as students the budget is, let's say, a little limited. The hotel and the flight were already pretty expensive, so we would like to know if there are some places where we could eat a good lunch at an affordable price (10 euros, let's say).

First we will stay in El Guinardo neighborhood, and afterwards in La Vall D'Hebron. Nevertheless, the recommended places to eat can also be in nearby neighborhoods of the previously-mentioned ones or somewhere as "downtown" as possible.

If you think I can easily find affordable places to eat by just exploring the city, that also works for me.

I hope I don't sound cheap.

Comment: I was there recently (2012) and most of the menus are outside the restaurants, so walking around would be the best advice unless someone with local knowledge comes on. Just be careful of the staff as they will try rush you in before you get a proper look.

Comment: Related [Inexpensive eating-out food in western Europe](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10824/241).

Comment: @Lt_Shade: Yeah, the rushing in thing happened to us in Paris this year, we'll be careful on that.

Comment: @mouviciel: Thanks for the link, did not find that.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. This question is pretty old and things changed a lot since then. Been to Barcelona several times I one of my favorites is El Reloj. It's located very good on Laietana Blv, it has the daily menu at very affordable prices and very good quality (10-15 euro depending on day). Also, the Paella is big, affordable and delicious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a cheap eat in spain (in general), look for the "Menu Del Dia" at lunch time; which usually come with an app, main (or main and dessert) and a glass of wine.

Near the Ramblas, there's Romesco (Carrer de Sant Pau, 28) which is cheap (it was cheap a couple of years ago).

Even if you are in Spain and want to eat Spanish food, don't forget to look at the many (turkish) kebab places where you should be able to get a good size sandwich and fries for cheap (YMMV).

If you can, try to keep bread, hard cheese and dry sausages and buy fruits and vegetables as you need them.

Good luck.

Comment: I had in mind the Doners (kebab places) as in Romania you can also eat pretty cheap there, but my girlfriend doesn't really approve of them, that's why I was looking for restaurants. Great tips, by the way. Also, most probably the supermarkets will be a breakfast/light-dinner source of food

Comment: About "menú del dia", please be aware that it is only common for lunch (noon) in working days. In fact, cheap and nutritive menus are marketed for working people in their lunch break. Therefore, they are uncommon in touristic areas, at nights or at weekends.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to eat on student budget, go eat where students eat. University canteens are one of the cheapest places to get a nutritive meal. If you are staying in Vall d'Hebron, you are near Mundet Campus and there must be some canteens there.

However, student canteens (and "menú del dia") are only common for lunch (noon) in working days. In fact, cheap and nutritive menus are marketed for students and working people in their lunch break. Therefore, they are uncommon in touristic areas, at nights or at weekends.